# How to test content_for using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I"m attempting to test my application_helper's `yield_for` method but I don't know the best way to go about it. I've tried the code below but get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: self.stub(:content_for).with(:foo).and_return('bar')
   Stub :content_for received unexpected message :with with (:foo)
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def yield_for(content_sym, default = '')
  content_for?(:content_sym) ? content_for(content_sym) : default
end
```

**application_helper_spec.rb**

```
describe '#yield_for' do
  it 'should fetch the yield' do
    self.stub(:content_for).with(:foo).and_return('bar')
    helper.yield_for(:foo).should == 'bar'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using rspec (3.1.0) and it should work with:

```
describe '#yield_for' do
  it 'should fetch the yield' do
    helper.content_for(:foo, 'bar')
    expect(helper.yield_for(:foo)).to eq('bar')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the stub on the helper

```
it 'should fetch the yield' do
  helper.stub(:content_for).with(:foo).and_return('bar')
  helper.yield_for(:foo).should == 'bar'
end
```

Got your test passing with this

```
def yield_for(content_sym, default = '')
  content_for(content_sym) ? content_for(content_sym) : default
end
```

Comment: This gives me: `Failure/Error: helper.yield_for(:foo).should == 'bar' expected: "bar" got: "" (using ==)`